# What's the difference between Struts tag <s:submit> and Struts jQuery tag <sj:submit>?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

Struts tag `<s:submit>` and Struts jQuery tag `<sj:submit>` both submit in the same way.  I mean, they refresh the page and forward to another to page. But I thought Struts jQuery tag implemented Ajax so the page should not be change while submitting. Am I correct?

I have implemented both tags in form, while submitting both are working same way.

```jsp
<s:form action="part!list" >
  <s:submit  action="part" method="list" />
</s:form>

<s:form action="part!list" >
  <sj:submit />
</s:form>
```

If I use `<sj:submit>` it works, but I add some struts tag button `<s:submit>` in the same form then it doesn't work. So, Struts tag won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably forgot to include `<sj:head/>` tag in the body of the `<head>`. This tag links JQuery `stylesheet` onto the page and other initial things, without it Ajax call is not made. See examples of correct submitting [`<sj:submit>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag).

If you make an Ajax call via `<sj:submit>` tag, the page should not refresh but the `targets` could be updated on successful result. If didn't include JQuery in the head of the page I don't think the form make any of the HTTP requests, it's behaving like you are not included the `action` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `id` attribute in the form tag and `targets` attribute in the `<sj:submit>` tag.

```
<s:form id="myForm" action="part!list">
  <sj:submit targets="result"/>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<s:submit/>` if there is not a requirement to trigger a ajax call. `<s:submit/>` uses the html mechanism to submit a form, but `<sj:submit />` is making an ajax call, check out the source [HERE](http://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.form.js), it explains how it works. If you need this form to make an ajax call, then just like @AleksandrM said, define the attribute `targets = "result"`, then you should have something like `<div id="result"/>`, which contains the result of the ajax call.

Comment: The element with `id=result` actually isn't need, if you don't want to show results. :)