# Struts 2 & jQuery grid, Retrieve the Grid Rows

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-grid

I am using jQuery and jQuery Grid 3.5.1 plugin in my Struts 2.1.8

I want to retrieve the multiselected rows on `<sj:submit>` button. I used `onClickTopics` for submit button.The jQuery code for retrieving grid rows is as:

```js
$.subscribe('getrows',function(event,data){
var s;
s=$('#grid_id').jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrow');
alert('selected rows:'+s);
});
```

the `alert` dialog always displays `null`. The grid is working fine.

The submit button is as:

```jsp
<sj:submit value="Rows" onClickTopics="getrows" button="true"/>
```

when I checked in firebug, on clicking the submit button it pops 1 error

```jsp
TypeError: c is undefined in file : struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.5.1
```

What is this error and why it is not working?

```jsp
<sjg:grid 
    gridModel="csvDetailList" 
    id="grid_id" 
     caption="Csv Files Pending"
    dataType="json" href="%{remoteurl}"
    multiselect="true" multiboxonly="true"
    >
    
    
    <sjg:gridColumn name="csv_filename" title="File" width="400"></sjg:gridColumn>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="month" title="Month" width="100"></sjg:gridColumn>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="year" title="Year" width="100"></sjg:gridColumn>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="upload_status" title="Upload Status" width="150" ></sjg:gridColumn>
    
    
</sjg:grid>
```

Comment: can you give the corresponding page code.

Comment: code of which page @Sathiyaraj ? Sorry

Comment: you will try to update your jQuery version. It will work fine ok

Comment: i also think its due to jquery older version, but updating jquery jar files in struts2 is giving lots of pain .Is struts2 2.1.8 is compatible with jquery 3.6 plugin

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17443250/1700321.

Comment: Other than you can download latest version jQuery lib and kept your js file. this file will include your presentation page view. It will overwrite the jquery libraries.

Comment: the problem is with `$.subscribe` . if i simply alert in this function it doesnot work n shows same error.

Comment: Is there any alternate to get the multiselect rows. I have to send them to Action Class

Comment: i also used onClick of `sj:submit` , But it doesnot retrieve `jqGrid` rows. Always returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your jsp code.

1. You have to put your `<sg:grid>` and `<sj:submit>` tag inside the `<s:form>` tag and
2. give an id to your form tag

Like below:

```
<s:form id="try">
<sg:grid>
</sg:grid>
<sj:submit id="grid_multi_getselectedbutton" value="Get Selected Rows" onClickTopics="getselectedids" button="true"/>
</s:form>
```

It will definitely work.

Comment: Half done @Amit. Error disappeared , and the jquery code working good.But the getGridParam returns null always.

Comment: i updated my qs with grid code.Please help if everything is right @Amit

Comment: @amit Thanks ... Finally Solved :)

Comment: @amit can u plz explain what was that jquery error and y form is neede to wrap the grid n submit??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var s = $('#grid_id').jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
alert('selected rows:'+s);
```